# Power on Atmega

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, atmega, atmel, atmega328p

I want to design an alarm circuit using Atmega328 microcontroller. How much voltage supply to the IC will be better? In Arduino I see that 5v power supply used. For Atmega328 which will be better? 5V or 3.7V ? I have 3.7V battery. If I use this 3.7V battery, will this work well?

Comment: Consult the datasheet fro the ATMega328 to see its recommended operating voltage spec.

Comment: operating voltage 1.8-5.5v.

Comment: Note that the maximum operating frequency goes up with voltage - 20MHz requires 5V. 1.8V can only operate to 4MHz.

Comment: Define "better." Better for what? Power savings? Compatible logic levels with other components? Component count on final design?

Comment: what it means 20MHz and 4MHz? In Arduino 16MHz cristal used. You mean this MHz or other?

Answer (score 4):

> If I use this 3.7V battery, will this work well?

The actual voltage of the battery will decrease from 4.2 V to 3.3 V, as the battery slowly goes from fully charged to fully discharged. The atmega328 accepts between 1.8 and 5.5 V power, so it will work under the full range of voltage from the battery without voltage regulation.

Note however that the full 1.8-5.5 V range is NOT officially supported for all atmega328 clock speeds:

[image: atmeg328 safe operation conditions]

The diagram is from [Sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/reducing-arduino-power-consumption/lowering-the-voltage) whom writes more on the subject. To summarize, it's safest to limit the speed to 10 MHz or so. I believe the default is 8 MHz anyway.

Comment: What it means by MHz. We supply dc voltage, there is no frequency. But 20MHz, 10MHz...… what is it?

Comment: The clock frequency of internal oscillator

Answer (score 3):

Every micro-controller has a data sheet that mentions 'Electrical Characteristics'.

As per [Atmega 328 data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf), Vcc can be of range \$2.7 - 5.5V\$

Comment: One more question, I want to connect a memory port for store sound files to the circuit, If I use a single USB, Can I use this single usb for both file transfer to memory and upload program in IC?

Comment: I think you should ask that as a separate question